# Which IAM roles and policies should I delete to not being charged by AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker

Are these roles to be deleted?

1. AmazonSageMakerServiceCatalogProductsLaunchRole
2. AmazonSageMakerServiceCatalogProductsUseRole
3. AWSServiceRoleForAmazonSageMakerNotebooks

Are these roles to be deleted?

1. AmazonSageMakerServiceCatalogProductsUseRole
2. Plus some execution policies

Is Jupyter server within sagemaker studio also be stopped for not being charged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AWS IAM is a free service** - you do not get charged for roles, policies or any other aspect of IAM.

From [the documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/#:%7E:text=IAM%20is%20a%20feature%20of,AWS%20services%20by%20your%20users.):

> IAM is a feature of your AWS account offered at no additional charge. You will be charged only for use of other AWS services by your users.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I had seen this link https://www.sagemakerworkshop.com/cleanup/workspace/, where it said to delete IAM roles, that's why I was confused whether or not to delete it.

Comment: Yes, if you've created roles for demoing, it's a good idea to then delete them if you don't need them but it's just for a cleaner UI - you're not charged. No worries!